# How to detect if a user received a text message?

Tags: ios, sms

Is there a way to detect, from your app, if the user received a text message. If this would be possible, what steps would have to be done to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. There is no public API available to monitor the messaging app activities. So you can't never detect whether SMS Sent or Received.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: Can you please tell me why it is wrong ? Is there any specific API available in iOS to detect SMS ?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: No, you can't identify whether that event happened due to an incoming call or sms or another app opened from the notification. All you can say is that some external event happened which may be an incoming call or a sms or another app opened by clicking the notification tray.

Comment: @MidhunMP good point, I wasn't sure if he needed explicitly SMS callbacks or just callbacks that will cover all SMS notifications as well as other events. I'll delete my comments, thanks!

Comment: I know tinder and bumble are doing something like this, they send you a message with a confirmation code and before you're able to write it the field gets populated with whatever you get in the SMS.

Comment: @DanielArechiga This answer is pretty old and it is not specifically about OTP. From iOS 12 onwards apple provides option to read the OTP messages, that's what you are seeing in tinder and other apps.

Comment: One might be tempted to use MessageFilterExtension to detect this, but it only gets invoked for unknown senders, not for SMS senders that are in the user's Contacts

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate's method `applicationWillResignActive` should do the trick ***(Though it will also be called for other things than just SMS messages)***.

It's called for incoming SMS messages, quoted right from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive):

> This method is called to let your app know that it is about to move from the active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call **or SMS message**) or when the user quits the app and it begins the transition to the background state. An app in the inactive state continues to run but does not dispatch incoming events to responders.

This is something we've used historically to pause our game when a text comes in. I haven't confirmed it works in iOS12 but at the time of posting this was definitely valid, Apple's docs even still state the SMS-message text for this callback, which leads me to believe it's valid.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted en masse today. Feel free to ask for clarification in these comments, thanks!

Comment: Why did this get a downvote ? Just went through the documentation and @Albert Renshaw answer seems accurate. Will test soon and upvote.